# How do I start a program after 10 minutes unless a key is pressed?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

`start "" "C:\Program Files\program.exe"`

- I want the program to start after ten minutes only if no keys are pressed.
- I want the program not to start if any key is pressed within the ten minutes.

What commands should I use in a .bat file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I want the program to start after ten minutes only if no keys are pressed.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off

    call :controlTimeout 600
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo A key was pressed
    ) else (
        echo Time Up
        start "" "C:\Program Files\program.exe"
    )

    exit /b 

:controlTimeout 
    setlocal
    start "" /belownormal /b cmd /q /d /c "timeout.exe %~1 /nobreak > nul"
    timeout.exe %~1 & tasklist | find "timeout" >nul 
    if errorlevel 1 ( set "exitCode=0" ) else ( 
        set "exitCode=1"
        taskkill /f /im timeout.exe 2>nul >nul
    )
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Credit: The above batch file is based on the StackOverflow answer [windows batch scripting: catch user reaction to "timeout" command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21443040/3536342) by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Errorlevel](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) - Almost all applications and utilities will set an exit code when they complete/terminate.
- [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) - TaskList displays all running applications and services with their Process ID (PID) This can be run on either a local or a remote computer.
- [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) - Delay execution for a few seconds or minutes, for use within a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a visual countdown, then there is a simple solution using TIMEOUT, which uses the `<backspace>` (0x08) character to position the countdown number that is displayed each second.

It appears like the number is in the middle of the string, but the output actually has the final 0 as the last character outptut, with either a backspace or space preceding. If the user presses a key, then the TIMEOUT is aborted and the final 0 is never output.

You can pipe the output to FINDSTR to test if 0 was the last number output.

```
timeout 600 | findstr "[^0-9]0$" >nul && start "" "C:\Program Files\program.exe"
```

If you get a Windows port of tee, then you can get a semi-functioning visual countdown, except the numbers mistakenly appear at the end of the message instead of the middle.

```
timeout 600 | tee countdown.txt
findstr "[^0-9]0$" countdown.txt >nul && start "" "C:\Program Files\program.exe"
del countdown.txt
```